# A embedded $C^1$ real function is locallyinvertible

Tags: real-analysis

$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  has maximum and minimum and $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$. Can I say that $f$ is locally invertible?

Answer (score 1):

No.   What if $f(x)=2$? Or any other constant.   You wouldn't have an inverse for anything other than a singleton point set